# How to clip a div with svg in css?

Tags: css

How to clip a div with svg?

Following is the code for a css animation:

```css
.liquid {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #4973ff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.liquid::after,
.liquid::before {
  content: "";
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -75%);
  background: #000;
}

.liquid::before {
  border-radius: 45%;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 1);
  animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

.liquid::after {
  border-radius: 40%;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
  animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="liquid"></div>
```

How can I embed/ clip the above animation inside a svg image?
Such that you will get a feeling of liquid filling the following image.

Following image :

[https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/3331/3331104.svg?token=exp=1619182384~hmac=11bada25343c186d8f2c99de7afec2f2](https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/3331/3331104.svg?token=exp=1619182384%7Ehmac=11bada25343c186d8f2c99de7afec2f2)

**(Remember it should be svg)**

Comment: May be try clip-path or mask with svg defs. It should work.

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.liquid` class.

Comment: No. Not like that. I want to clip the .liquid class inside the svg image. The svg image is going to contain the .liquid class animation.

Comment: I hope you got me.

Comment: Can someone suggest some ideas? Please.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this if I'm understanding right.

```
.element {
     clip-path: url(#svgClipPathID);
}
```

This is a very good article about clip-path:
[https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/#:~:text=The%20clip%2Dpath%20property%20is%20used%20to%20specify%20a%20clipping,in%20the%20CSS%20Shapes%20module](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/#:%7E:text=The%20clip%2Dpath%20property%20is%20used%20to%20specify%20a%20clipping,in%20the%20CSS%20Shapes%20module).

Comment: I tried that way. But I'm using an svg image element. Not working as expected.

Comment: Please understand that I'm not using a path to clip. Instead using an svg image.

Comment: Ok, sorry my bad